# leaflet realtime: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I have a map which is using leaflet realtime.

I set up the leaflet realtime like the description on [github](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime). and with the url in the example it worked very well, but when I use the json string directly I will get the following error-message:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data undefined leaflet-realtime.min.js:4:3695

the code looks like this:

```
var geojsonFeature = {"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-64.90913344523922, 31.274686201725011]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {}};


    var map = L.map('map', 
        {
            center: [<?php echo $StartNorth; ?>, <?php echo $StartEast; ?>],
            zoom: <?php echo $StartZoomLevel; ?>,
            layers: [BasemapAT_basemap, geoJSONLayerNone],

            zoomControl: false,

            contextmenu: true,
            contextmenuWidth: 200,
            contextmenuItems: [{
                text: 'Koordinaten anzeigen',
                callback: showCoordinates
            }, {
                text: 'Karte hier zentrieren',
                callback: centerMap
            }, '-', {
                text: 'Zoom in',
                icon: 'assets/leaflet-contextmenu/dist/images/zoom-in.png',
                callback: zoomIn
            }, {
                text: 'Zoom out',
                icon: 'assets/leaflet-contextmenu/dist/images/zoom-out.png',
                callback: zoomOut
            }]
        }
    )
        realtime = L.realtime({
        geojsonFeature,
        //url: 'https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/',
        crossOrigin: true,
        type: 'json'
    }, {
        interval: 3 * 1000,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {
                'icon': L.icon({
                    iconUrl: 'leaflet/images/marker-icon-vehicle.png',
                        iconSize:       [16, 16],
                        iconAnchor:     [1, 8],
                        popupAnchor:    [7, 0]
                })
            });
        }}).addTo(map);
```

theoretical it should work, but I can't explain myself why not.
can anybody give me a tip?

Comment: Your `geojsonFeature` is an object, not a string as you say in your question. Is that intentional?

Comment: Actually, looking at the documentation from the page you linked, it doesn't look like it's possible to use a JSON string as a parameter to `L.realtime`

Comment: yes, because I saw it similar in other examples (https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime/issues/69) on the web.
the string stored in `geojsonFeature ` will be generated automatically in interval on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the conclusion is, that leaflet realtime seams to be a great project but does not work for me.

therefore i have created a personal solution, which add and remove a `L.geoJSON` layer:

```
    function refreshTable(){
        //code which creates TTvehicleObj
        function addTTlayer() {

            TTJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
                        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: vehicleMarker});
                        },
                        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                            if (feature.properties.Ignition == 0 && feature.properties.Standstill == 1) {
                                    vehicleParking = '<span class="label label-default">P</span>&nbsp;';
                                } else if (feature.properties.Ignition == 1 && feature.properties.Standstill == 1) {
                                    vehicleParking = '<span class="label label-primary">P</span>&nbsp;';
                                } else {
                                    vehicleParking = '';
                                }
                                layer.bindPopup(vehicleParking+'<strong>'+feature.properties.Funknummer+'</strong>&nbsp;|&nbsp;'+feature.properties.Position);
                            }
                        });

            TTJsonLayer.addData(TTvehicleObj);
            TTJsonLayer.addTo(map);

            function refreshTTlayer() {
            if (typeof TTJsonLayer === 'undefined') {
                addTTlayer();
            } else {
                map.removeLayer(TTJsonLayer);
                addTTlayer();
            }
        }

        refreshTTlayer();

        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(refreshTable, 60000);
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs state:

> The source can be one of:
>
> 1. a string with the URL to get data from
> 2. an options object that is passed to fetch for fetching the data
> 3. a function in case you need more freedom.
>
> In case you use a function, the function should take two callbacks as
>   arguments: fn(success, error), with the callbacks:
>
> 1. a success callback that takes GeoJSON as argument: success(
>      features)
> 2. an error callback that should take an error object and an error
>      message (string) as argument: error( error, 
>      message)

According to the docs what you're trying is not valid as a source. You could do it by using a function. Alternatively there's:

```
update(<GeoJSON> featureData?)
```

Which is a method you can use to pass in your data.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I am unable to figure out, how does the function look like...